# NEED ANSWER: Android stackoverflow error while serializing data

Tags: java, android, performance, android-intent

**See Edit before answering/commenting please!**

So I have the following code where I am passing data between activities in the onPostExecute() method of my asynctask, and my app is constantly crashing with a stackoverflow error: (note: this is not my full activity)

```
public class Wrapper{
    public Elements gradeList;
}

private class infoGetter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Wrapper> {

    ProgressDialog progress;

    public infoGetter(WelcomeLogin activity){

        progress = new ProgressDialog(activity);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        progress.setTitle("Logging in:");
        progress.setMessage("Please wait...");
        progress.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Wrapper doInBackground(Void... params) {

        Wrapper w = new Wrapper();

        String studentID = studentID2.getText().toString();
        String username = user.getText().toString();
        String password = pass.getText().toString();

        String loginURL = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents/j_security_check";
        String userDataUrl = "https://parents.mtsd.k12.nj.us/genesis/parents?tab1=" + tab1 + "&tab2=" + tab2 + "&tab3=" + tab3 + "&studentid=" + studentID + "&action=" + action;

        Response response = new GradeFetcher().getRequest(userDataUrl);
        Document loggedInDocument = new GradeFetcher().postRequest(loginURL, username, password, studentID, response);
        Elements grades = new GradeFetcher().gradeExtractor(loggedInDocument);

        for(Element grade : grades) {

            Log.e("Grades: ",grade.text());

        }

        w.gradeList = grades;
        Log.e("MESSAGE: ","Going to onPostExecute");


        return w;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Wrapper w) {

        Log.e("MESSAGE: ", "Starting onPostExecute");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String serial = gson.toJson(w.gradeList,Elements.class);
        Intent GradeList = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainList.class);
        GradeList.putExtra("grades", serial);
        startActivity(GradeList);

        Log.e("MESSAGE: ", "Going to next activity now");
        progress.dismiss();


    }
}
```

And I get the following error:

```
08-03 13:33:28.592  27871-28323/com.aurum.gradebook E/MESSAGE:﹕ Going to onPostExecute
08-03 13:33:28.604  27871-27871/com.aurum.gradebook E/MESSAGE:﹕ Starting     onPostExecute
08-03 13:33:37.013  27871-27871/com.aurum.gradebook E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL         EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.aurum.gradebook, PID: 27871
java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
        at java.io.StringWriter.write(StringWriter.java:147)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.string(JsonWriter.java:534)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.writeDeferredName(JsonWriter.java:402)
        at com.google.gson.stream.JsonWriter.value(JsonWriter.java:417)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.write(TypeAdapters.java:362)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapters$13.write(TypeAdapters.java:346)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:96)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:60)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:99)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:219)
         at   com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRun timeTypeWrapper.java:68)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterF
```

I can't find where/what is causing this to occur. Please help!

**EDIT 1:** I now know that my error lies in the statement :

```
String serial = gson.toJson(w.gradeList,Elements.class);
```

which I assume means my "w.gradeList" is too big. However, this is a simple Jsoup Elements object containing about 6 scrapped grades(e.g. "100%) so I do not see how this can be so. I understand that this error is most likely due to a circular reference but I can't find any place where this would occur. **(I also do not want to resort to using temporary files or anything other than intents to pass my data as they should be perfectly capable of doing so)**

Comment: check your data structures on loops/cycles, In case there's a loop in your data structure, i.e parent -> child -> grandchild -> parent, serializer may exceed all available memory, trying to serialize this infinite sequence of data.

Comment: @RafaelOsipov Thanks for the quick response, I have done so and I really can't see anywhere recursion would occur

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, you are able to put up to 1MB of data in a Bundle inside Intent. Though it is not documented, there is a issue open in android aosp.
issue url: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=5878

your initial problem lies in `String serial = gson.toJson(w.gradeList,Elements.class);` Even if you succeed to overcome this this error, you will face the hardest challenge in `GradeList.putExtra("grades", serial);` here your `serial` is too big to carry and apparently it is `8MB` [by understanding the stack trace].

How to workaround this limitation:

As you clearly can't cross this limit, what you can do now. write the content to a storage. I am not sure whether you can write this amount of data to SharedPreference (I believe it can be done) but you can do write in a temporary file and then send the file uri to the activity. There you read again from the file.
I hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the response; I understand your solution but im curious as to why my serial object is too big as it only contains 6 Element objects?

Comment: could you share your Elements  class? Definitely there are something infinite loop occurring while serializing it.

Comment: the Elements class is part of the Jsoup library I am using to scrape web data. Should I still share it? (It is a very long class)

Comment: I would suggest you to print w.gradeList exhaustively. I believe you will be able to see that it is running an infinite loop.

Comment: Oh, Each Element object has lot of information. So just use your own data model and store only your necessary values then serialize.

Comment: Each Element object is just a grade such as "100%"

Comment: then, I would like to suggest you to print w.gradeList exhaustively. I believe you will be able to see that it is running an infinite loop

Comment: When I did this, it functioned as it should (printed out values normally). I tried your suggestion of using sharedPreferences to send the serialized object, but I am getting the same error

Comment: cause, your first problem is the toJson call

Comment: Would you recommend using a writing to/reading a temporary file or extending the application class to persist data?

Comment: I would prefer to writing it to the file.